# loop in time using laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

please i need your help to get time looping
i have a start time and end time , and i want to list of array times with added 30 minutes i am trying to get code like below but array return empty

```php
$available_times = [];
$module = $garage->work_time;
$from = date("H:i", strtotime($module->from));
$to = date("H:i", strtotime($module->to));
$time = strtotime($from);
$new_time = date("H:i", strtotime('30 minutes', $time));
if(!in_array(date("h:i a" , strtotime($new_time)), $available_times))
{
    array_push($available_times , date("h:i a" , strtotime($new_time)));
}
while($new_time < $to)
{
    $time = strtotime($new_time);
    $new_time = date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $new_time));
    if($new_time . ':00' >= $to)
    {
        break;
    }

    if(!in_array(date("h:i a" , strtotime($new_time)), $available_times))
    {
        array_push($available_times , date("h:i a" , strtotime($new_time)));
    }

}
return $available_times;
```

can any one help me i want a list like that

```
[
  "9:30 am",
"10:00 am",
"10:30 am",
"11:00 am",
"11:30 am",
]
```

..etc,

Comment: If your start time is 8:12 will your next time be 8:30 or 8:42?

Comment: 8:42, in my example start time at 9:00

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by using a mixture of [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$start = new DateTime($garage->work_time->from);
$end = new DateTime($garage->work_time->to);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$available_times = [];
foreach ($period as $time) {
    $available_times[] = $time->format('h:i a');
}

return $available_times;
```

---

Alternatively, since Laravel comes with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), you could use [CarbonPeriod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period) instead:

```
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

$periods = CarbonPeriod::create($garage->work_time->from, '30 minutes', $garage->work_time->to);

$available_times = array_map(function ($period) {
    return $period->format('h:i a');
}, $periods->toArray());
```

Comment: many thanks for your response .. it's work by tow ways

Comment: @mohamed Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by change time in DB to 24 hours 17:00:00 instead of 5:00:00 in end time

```
 $available_times = [];

        $from = date("H:i", strtotime($module->from));
        $to = date("H:i", strtotime($module->to));


        if (!in_array(date("h:i a", strtotime($from)), $available_times)) {
            array_push($available_times, date("h:i a", strtotime($from)));
        }

        $time_from = strtotime($from);

        $new_time = date("H:i", strtotime('30 minutes', $time_from));
        if (!in_array(date("h:i a", strtotime($new_time)), $available_times)) {
            array_push($available_times, date("h:i a", strtotime($new_time)));
        }

        while ($new_time < $to) {
            $time = strtotime($new_time);
            $new_time = date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $time));
            if ($new_time . ':00' >= $to) {
                break;
            }
//                //Push 3
            if (!in_array(date("h:i a", strtotime($new_time)), $available_times)) {
                array_push($available_times, date("h:i a", strtotime($new_time)));
            }

        }

        return $available_times;
```